# Бастард и байстрюк

Tags: этимология

Незаконнорожденных сыновей в Европе называли бастардами, а в России — байстрюками. Родственные это слова или нет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Почему же нет? Виноградов В.В. считает родственными. В "Истории слов" он [пишет](http://wordhist.narod.ru/struckij.html):

> ... слово стрюцкий. В современном литературном языке оно уже устарело. Правда, оно еще встречается, хотя и не так часто, и в современном просторечном употреблении. Оно внесено в «Толковый словарь» Д. Н. Ушакова и определено так: "пустой, неосновательный, ничтожный человек" (Ушаков, 4, с. 568).
>
> Еще раньше оно было зарегистрировано Далем в «Толковом словаре» (1882, 4, с. 354): «Стрюцкий и стрюцкой человек, подлый, дрянной, презренный». А. И. Соболевский, знавший это слово в живом московском употреблении, указал на этимологическую связь его с бастрюк, особенно с прилагательным бастрюцкий (сын) (РФВ, 1911, № 3—4, т. 66, с. 345. «Мелочи»). Ср. шлык из башлык.Бастрюк же у Даля обозначает "выродок"; "пригульный, небрачнорожденный" (с пометой: воровское) (сл. Даля, 1880, 1, с.53).
>
> А. Преображенский признал это объяснение вероятным. Поэтому, хотя сам слышал это слово лишь в форме прилагательного стрюцкий, он восстанавливает как первичное слово: «стрюк, Р. стрюка; стрюцкий бранное и ироническое без определенного значения, в роде презренный, дрянной» (Преображенский 2, с. 405).
>
> Бастрык, бастрюк — слова, известные областным, преимущественно южным [великорусским] говорам и воровскому жаргону. Они находят соответствие в укр. байстрюк, байструк и в польск. bastrak. Возможно, что и в русских говорах бастрык, бастрюк являются заимствованием из украинского языка. В украинский же и польский языки это слово вошло из нем. bastard.
>
> Есть основания предполагать, что в литературный язык слово стрюцкий попало из речи деклассированных люмпен-пролетариев, из «блатной музыки», из низовых жаргонов города, где оно в свою очередь в деформированном виде укрепилось не без влияния южно-западнорусской народной речи. Но какова бы ни была этимология слова стрюцкий, оно приблизилось к русскому литературному языку из жаргонов и диалектов устной речи не ранее второй половины XIX в. Оно употребляется и комментируется в комедии А. Н. Островского: «В чужом пиру похмелье» (д. 1, явл. 4). Им пользуется купец Андрей Титыч:
>
> > «...эти *стрюцкие* такие дела с нами делают, что смеху подобно.
> >
> > **Лизавета Ивановна.** Что у вас за слова такие! Какие-то *стрюцкие*!
> >
> > **Андрей Титыч** Уж это слово им недаром дано-с. Другой весь-то грош стоит, а такого из себя барина доказывает, и не подст упайся, — засудит; а дал ему целковый или там больше, глядя по делу, да подпоил, так он хоть спирю плясать пойдет».

Comment: Я не видел этого у Виноградова, но вообще-то он тут про другое слово слово говорит...  
Чио же касается байстрюк - бастард, то совершенноь немотивировано Й и стяжение согласных с пропажей А, совершенно не свойственная славянским. Скорее гласная бы втавилась. Виногладов этого не объясняеь, что ставит под сомнение всю цепочку.

Answer (score 2):

Нет. Непонятна даже сама идея: почему их надо считать родственными? 
Фонетически далекие, значение разное (бастарды исторически — незаконнорожденные дети царственных особ и князей). Никакого внятного обоснования я не встречал.

Что касается самого слова *байстрю*к, то слово темное, но фонетически можно предположить тюркское происхождение. Есть еще "еврейская" версия — от "бекицер", но уж очень далеко звучание...

Comment: Гм........

Comment: Я вижу постоянный флуд. Версий не вижу. Переделывать не буду.